# Update from select statement and group by clause in Sybase Ase

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-update, subquery, sap-ase

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am trying to run an update statement like the one below

```
update A set COL1 = 3 ,COL2 = getDate(), COL3 = '6' 
from A ACC INNER JOIN 
(select COL5,COL6
from B B sp INNER JOIN  C C s ON B.COL1 = C.COL1
INNER JOIN A Z on (Z.COL6 = C.COL7)
where B.COL8 = 'VVVV' AND B.COL9 = 'U'
group by COL5,COL6) A on (A.COl5 = ACC.COL5 AND A.COL6 = ACC.COL6)
```

i am using Sybase Ase 16.0.
It is throwing an error **"You cannot use a derived table in the FROM clause of an UPDATE or DELETE statement."**

How can i use select with group by with an update statement.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: If this is a real query, you can move the conditions from the `from` to a `where` clause using `exists`.  You are not referencing any columns in the other tables.

Comment: You can't use `update` combined with `group by` in Sybase ASE. Create a temporary table and update from there.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the Gordon Linoff and it worked well.

Thanks a lot.
Best regards